# Ubuntu downloaded as .iso file on mac

Tags: system-installation, macbook-pro, disk-utility

Everytime I download Ubuntu onto my mac laptop, it is downloaded as an .iso file.  I cannot open the file because it tells me in Launchpad:

```
hdiutil: mount failed - No such file or directory
```

Comment: What do I need to be doing to install Ubuntu onto my mac?

Comment: You need to burn that ISO to a DVD or USB drive. Please read: http://www.howtogeek.com/187410/how-to-install-and-dual-boot-linux-on-a-mac/

Comment: much appreciated!  @Zacharee1 Will do, with an update.

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed to download as an ISO. You wouldn't simply open the file to install ubuntu on your computer. It's a full operating system not just a regular piece of software.

You would have to create a bootable USB using that iso. See documentation here:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

Comment: That's what I gathered @Grant Seltzer I just wasn't positive.  Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: No problem @LoganLedbetter

Comment: When I try to convert the iso file to an img file in Launchpad, I am receiving this error: hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/path/to/ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.img~/path/to/ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso
hdiutil: convert: no input file specified
Usage: hdiutil convert -format <format> -o <outfile> [options] <image>
 hdiutil convert -help

Comment: Should the iso file be in a different location for launchpad to find it?  Or am I missing something more?

Comment: Nm i answered my own question and successfully installed UBUNTU @Grant Seltzer

Comment: Why would you need to convert to an img file?  Congrats btw @LoganLedbetter